# How can i add more streams to icecast server through butt

Tags: stream, icecast, internet-radio

I'm building an icecast server using butt. The stream runs on 320 kbps and it's hard on bad internet connections. So, I decided to create a 2nd stream, so that anyone who has a bad connection can change to it.
The problem I cannot find out how to put another stream on the same icecast I already use.

Answer (score 0):

You need something called a *transcoder*. Basically it's both a client and a source. It connects to the full quality stream, decodes it and encodes it with a different codec or at a lower quality and then sends it to a new mount point on the same or a different Icecast server.

There are quite a few options. You can just use ffmpeg/avconv, or you can use liquidsoap, or ezstream, or...

My personal recommendation would be to first optimize the primary stream for quality, not for bitrate, e.g. Opus at an average of 128-140 kbit/s will probably beat 320 kbit/s MP3 hands down. MP3 is an ancient codec by internet standards, the technology behind it is 20 years old or older. If you positively need a MP3 stream to support bad client software, then you should transcode **to** it.

Standard disclaimer: The format of your files is *irrelevant* for your primary stream format, as 99% of all use cases require the source client to run an encoder.